# How to use locationFromAddress in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geocoding

```
String _address = ""; // create this variable

void _getPlace() async {
  List<Placemark> newPlace = await _geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(_position.latitude, _position.longitude);

  // this is all you need
  Placemark placeMark  = newPlace[0]; 
  String name = placeMark.name;
  String subLocality = placeMark.subLocality;
  String locality = placeMark.locality;
  String administrativeArea = placeMark.administrativeArea;
  String postalCode = placeMark.postalCode;
  String country = placeMark.country;
  String address = "${name}, ${subLocality}, ${locality}, ${administrativeArea} ${postalCode}, ${country}";
  
  print(address);

  setState(() {
    _address = address; // update _address
  });
```

how to replace placemarkFromCoordinates() to locationFromAddress() because convert the address from user input field then change to get the long and lat. Please help me thenks!

Comment: so you want lat long from the user's address ?

Comment: yes, i use google API geocoding and i want to convert the user's address from input field then convert the coordinate to lat and long. Can you help me using this function  locationFromAddress() ? I'm a beginner. I really appreciate if you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both from address to coordinates and vice versa.(with older flutter version & without null safety you can use this)

**1st way using [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)**

```
Future<void> getGeoCoderData() async {
    List<Location> locations =
        await locationFromAddress("Gronausestraat 710, Enschede");
    debugPrint("Address to Lat long ${locations.first.latitude} : ${locations.first.longitude}");

    List<Placemark> placemarks =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(52.216653, 6.9462204);
    debugPrint("Lat Long to Address: ${placemarks.first.street} : ${placemarks.first.locality}");
  }
```

Output:
[image]

**2nd way using [geocoder](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder)**

```
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';

// From a query / address 
final query = "1600 Amphiteatre Parkway, Mountain View";
var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query);
var first = addresses.first;
print("${first.featureName} : ${first.coordinates}");

// From coordinates to address
final coordinates = new Coordinates(1.10, 45.50);
addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
first = addresses.first;
print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
```

Comment: did you implement API for geocode in this coding above?

Comment: yes, i used that in one of my app with flutter older version (without null-safty).

Comment: you  are using geocoding so updated my answer accordingly too.

Comment: but, may i see the code with locationFromAddress() function instead of above?

Comment: yes, in 1st way added both methods locationFromAddress & placemarkFromCoordinates with output.

Comment: for locationFromAddress you need to pass 2 parameters 1st is address & 2nd is localeIdentifier.

Comment: can you help me how to insert the localIdentifier? and i convert the address from search.text where the search come from TextEditingController address = TextEditingController(); as user should input their own full address .

Comment: The localeIdentifier should be formatted using the syntax: [languageCode]_[countryCode] check geo coding  readme section they mentioned.